# Tensorflow keras fit - accuracy and loss both increasing drastically

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

ubuntu - 20.04

tensorflow 2.2

dataset used = MNIST

I am testing tensorflow and i notice that validation `sparse_categorical_accuracy` (accuracy) and validation `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` (loss) both are increasing together which, does not make sense to me. I think the validation loss should be going down and validation accuracy increasing as the training progresses. Or, incase of overfitting, validation loss increasing and validation accuracy going down. But, validation loss and validation accuracy both are increasing as the training progresses. The training schedule however, is progressing according to expectation i.e training loss going down and training accuracy going up

Here is the code and the output:

```
#testing without preprocess monsoon
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as k
from tensorflow.keras import layers as l
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_t,y_t),(x_te,y_te) = mnist.load_data()
x_t = x_t.reshape(60000,-1)
x_te = x_te.reshape(10000,-1)

d_x_t = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_t)
d_y_t = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_t)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d_x_t,d_y_t)).shuffle(1000).batch(32)

d_x_te = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_te)
d_y_te = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_te)
dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.zip((d_x_te,d_y_te)).shuffle(1000,seed=42).batch(32)

inp = k.Input((784,))
x = l.BatchNormalization()(inp)
x1 = l.Dense(1024,activation='relu',name='dense_1')(x)
x1=l.Dropout(0.5)(x1)
x1 = l.BatchNormalization()(x1)
x2 = l.Dense(512,activation='relu',name='dense_2')(x1)
x3 = l.Dense(512,activation='relu',name='dense_3')(x)
x = x3+x2

x=l.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = l.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = l.Dense(10,activation='relu',name='dense_4')(x)
predictions = l.Dense(10,activation=None,name='preds')(x)
model = k.Model(inputs=inp,outputs=predictions)

opt=tfa.optimizers.MovingAverage(
    k.optimizers.Adam(),
    True,
    0.99,
    None,
    'MovingAverage',
    clipnorm=5
)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=k.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
print('# Fit model on training data')
history = model.fit(dataset,
                    epochs=30,
                    steps_per_epoch=1875,
                    validation_data = dataset_test,
                    validation_steps = 313)

print('\nhistory dict:', history.history)
model.evaluate(dataset_test,batch_size=32,steps=331)
```

The learning evolution that i am getting is:

```
# Fit model on training data
Epoch 1/30
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/nitin/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1817: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
1875/1875 [==============================] - 49s 26ms/step - loss: 0.3614 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.8913 - val_loss: 0.3355 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9548
Epoch 2/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 49s 26ms/step - loss: 0.1899 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9427 - val_loss: 1.2028 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9641
Epoch 3/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 51s 27ms/step - loss: 0.1546 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9521 - val_loss: 1.6385 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9673
Epoch 4/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 38s 20ms/step - loss: 0.1357 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9585 - val_loss: 2.8285 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9697
Epoch 5/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 38s 20ms/step - loss: 0.1253 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9608 - val_loss: 3.8489 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9697
Epoch 6/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1149 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9646 - val_loss: 2.1872 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9699
Epoch 7/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1094 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9646 - val_loss: 2.9429 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9695
Epoch 8/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.1066 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9667 - val_loss: 5.6166 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 9/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0991 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9688 - val_loss: 3.9547 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 10/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0948 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9701 - val_loss: 4.8149 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9713
Epoch 11/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0850 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9727 - val_loss: 7.4974 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9712
Epoch 12/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0879 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9719 - val_loss: 4.3669 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9714
Epoch 13/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0817 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9743 - val_loss: 9.2499 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9725
Epoch 14/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0805 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9737 - val_loss: 7.5436 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9716
Epoch 15/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0798 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9751 - val_loss: 14.2331 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9712
Epoch 16/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0745 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9757 - val_loss: 7.9517 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9715
Epoch 17/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0745 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9761 - val_loss: 7.9719 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9702
Epoch 18/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0741 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9763 - val_loss: 13.8696 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9665
Epoch 19/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0728 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9760 - val_loss: 20.2949 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9688
Epoch 20/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 45s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0699 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9775 - val_loss: 8.8696 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9713
Epoch 21/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0699 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9777 - val_loss: 12.9682 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9723
Epoch 22/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0674 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9781 - val_loss: 61.1677 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9692
Epoch 23/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0651 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9798 - val_loss: 21.3270 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9697
Epoch 24/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 31s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0624 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9800 - val_loss: 62.2778 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9685
Epoch 25/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0665 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9792 - val_loss: 24.9327 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9687
Epoch 26/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 46s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0605 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9805 - val_loss: 42.0141 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9700
Epoch 27/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0601 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9806 - val_loss: 54.8586 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9695
Epoch 28/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0583 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9811 - val_loss: 25.3613 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9680
Epoch 29/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 29s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0576 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9811 - val_loss: 23.2299 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9710
Epoch 30/30
1875/1875 [==============================] - 30s 16ms/step - loss: 0.0566 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9817 - val_loss: 16.5671 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9728

history dict: {'loss': [0.36135926842689514, 0.1898646354675293, 0.15456895530223846, 0.13569727540016174, 0.12525275349617004, 0.1148592159152031, 0.10943067818880081, 0.1066298857331276, 0.09912335127592087, 0.09476170688867569, 0.08501157909631729, 0.0879492461681366, 0.08170024305582047, 0.08047273010015488, 0.07976552098989487, 0.07453753799200058, 0.07450901716947556, 0.07413797080516815, 0.07278618961572647, 0.0698995441198349, 0.06988336145877838, 0.06740442663431168, 0.06507138162851334, 0.06242847815155983, 0.0665266141295433, 0.06050613150000572, 0.06005210056900978, 0.05830719694495201, 0.05763527378439903, 0.05664650723338127], 'sparse_categorical_accuracy': [0.8913000226020813, 0.9427499771118164, 0.9521499872207642, 0.9585333466529846, 0.9607999920845032, 0.9645500183105469, 0.9645666480064392, 0.9666833281517029, 0.9687666893005371, 0.9701166749000549, 0.9726999998092651, 0.9719499945640564, 0.9742666482925415, 0.9736999869346619, 0.9750999808311462, 0.9757000207901001, 0.9760833382606506, 0.9763166904449463, 0.9759833216667175, 0.977483332157135, 0.9777166843414307, 0.9780833125114441, 0.9798333048820496, 0.9800000190734863, 0.9792333245277405, 0.9805499911308289, 0.9805999994277954, 0.9810666441917419, 0.9810666441917419, 0.9816833138465881], 'val_loss': [0.33551061153411865, 1.2028071880340576, 1.6384732723236084, 2.828489065170288, 3.8488738536834717, 2.187160015106201, 2.9428975582122803, 5.6166462898254395, 3.954725503921509, 4.814915657043457, 7.4974141120910645, 4.366909503936768, 9.24986457824707, 7.543578147888184, 14.233136177062988, 7.951717853546143, 7.971870422363281, 13.869564056396484, 20.29490089416504, 8.869643211364746, 12.968180656433105, 61.167701721191406, 21.327049255371094, 62.27778625488281, 24.932708740234375, 42.01411437988281, 54.85857009887695, 25.361297607421875, 23.229896545410156, 16.56712532043457], 'val_sparse_categorical_accuracy': [0.954800009727478, 0.9641000032424927, 0.9672999978065491, 0.9696999788284302, 0.9696999788284302, 0.9699000120162964, 0.9695000052452087, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9713000059127808, 0.9711999893188477, 0.9714000225067139, 0.9725000262260437, 0.9715999960899353, 0.9711999893188477, 0.9714999794960022, 0.9702000021934509, 0.9664999842643738, 0.9688000082969666, 0.9713000059127808, 0.9722999930381775, 0.9692000150680542, 0.9696999788284302, 0.968500018119812, 0.9686999917030334, 0.9700000286102295, 0.9695000052452087, 0.9679999947547913, 0.9710000157356262, 0.9728000164031982]}
302/331 [==========================>...] - ETA: 0s - loss: 17.1192 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9725WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 331 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
313/331 [===========================>..] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 16.5671 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9728
[16.567113876342773, 0.9728000164031982]
```

Comment: Why is activation function in last dense layer None. Ain't softmax the best choice?

Comment: Loss computation does not require softmax application. Just the logits. Which is one of the major reasons the softmax is the best choice. `k.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)`

Answer (score 0):

If training loss is decreasing and validation one is increasing when it's likely you've overfitted the model.

Also I have some doubts about this line:
`x = x3+x2`
As I understand, you want to create short connection. But in keras you should use `Add` layer to do this.

Comment: I get the point about overfitting. What beats me is validation accuracy going up. I cannot think of a reason to even start debugging. I will try it by changing `x=x2+x3` with a layer but, what difference might it cause?

Comment: changing `x=x2+x3` with `x=tf.keras.layers.Add()([x2,x3])` did not alleviate the problem. Validation accuracy is still going up and so is validation loss

Comment: When I ran the code with model architecture changed, the test results are [0.11449366807937622, 0.9829999804496765]. What I did was to remove first batchnorm layer and remove the layer concatenation. The validation loss found to be in the range of 0.1 throughout training.